# express-openapi-validator does not validates the request against yaml file

Tags: node.js, express, swagger-ui, express-openapi-validator

When hitting endpoint, express-openapi-validator does not validate the request.

api.yaml

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: API Docs
  description: Authentication
  version: 1.0.0

servers:
  - url: http://localhost:3030/oauth
    description: Local server

paths:
  /token:
    post:
      summary: access token
      description: generates a new token
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                client_id:
                  type: string
                client_secret:
                  type: string
              required:
                - client_id
                - client_secret
      responses: 
        200:
          description: ''
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  access_token:
                    type: string
                  token_type:
                    type: string
                  expires_in:
                    type: number
        401:
          description: ''
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  name:
                    type: string
                  message:
                    type: string
                  status:
                    type: number
  
  /third_party_access_token/update:
    post:
      summary: ''
      description: ''
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                partner_id:
                  type: number
      responses: 
        200:
          description: ''
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  access_token:
                    type: string
                  token_type:
                    type: string
                  expires_in:
                    type: number
        400:
          description: if passed invalid partner id
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  name:
                    type: string
                  message:
                    type: string
                  status:
                    type: number
```

app.ts file

```
import cors from "cors";
import express from 'express';
import * as OpenApiValidator from 'express-openapi-validator';
import * as oauth from './routes/oauth.route';

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use(
    OpenApiValidator.middleware({
        apiSpec: './api.yaml',
        validateRequests: true,
        validateResponses: true,
    }),
);

app.use('/oauth', oauth.router);

app.use((err: any, req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
    // 7. Customize errors
    console.error('Error is ',err); // dump error to console for debug
    res.status(err.status || 500).json({
      message: err.message,
      errors: err.errors,
    });
});

export default app;
```

server.ts file

```
import express from 'express';
import app from './app';
const swaggerUI = require('swagger-ui-express');
const yaml = require('yamljs');
const main = express(); 
const port = 3030; // default port to listen

// Serve the OpenAPI spec
const swaggerJsDocs = yaml.load('./api.yaml');
main.use('/oauth/docs', swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(swaggerJsDocs));

// define a route handler for the default home page
main.use('/', app);

main.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Versions
"express-openapi-validator": "^4.13.7"
"express": "^4.17.1"

Is I am missing something or the order of middlewares is not correct. I tried all things but does not seem to work.
Thank you.

Comment: Anyone got any solution for this problem. I am having same issue. please let me know or update the answer.